# Port forwarding - no request received

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding, wireshark

On my router I am forwarding port `:80` to my ubuntu pc's port `:80`.

On the ubuntu pc is running *Nginx* reverse proxy which forwards the requests to other machines.

The problem is, *Nginx* receives no requests, and therefore the setup does not work.

I have run `sudo tcpdump -ni any port 80 -vv -s0 -w http.pcap` on the ubuntu pc, to see that the machine receives the requests.

When I opened the `http.pcap` in *wireshark* I see black packets with TCP Retrasmission:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHuG3.png

Nginx does not receive anything, there is no firewall enabled on the pc. 
The client receives timeout.

I only got theese packets. What does it mean? How to fix it?

Redirecting the port to different machine works.

Answer (score 0):

Your capture shows that packets on port 80 *are* received as they should, but your Ubuntu server *does not respond to them.* You see the client trying again after a second, then after a few seconds, but there is no SYN+ACK response which would allow the TCP connection to be established.

(Black just means that Wireshark recognizes it as a retransmission of a previously seen packet.)

The real HTTP request would only show up starting with the *fourth* packet, i.e. only once the TCP connection has been fully established. Nginx also won't be informed about a connection until it is established.

- Check your server's firewall (iptables, ufw, nft) to make sure it allows inbound connections. (Also, just in case you have a very paranoid configuration, make sure it doesn't block outbound responses either...)
- Yes, even if "there is no firewall enabled on the pc", check the firewall *anyway.* Run `sudo iptables-save`, then run `sudo nft list ruleset`.
- Check whether other software can receive connections on port 80: stop nginx, install netcat, run `sudo nc -vvlp 80`, try to connect.
- Check whether the server responds to connections on other ports, e.g. 443 or 8080 or 12345.
- If your server has multiple network interfaces, check the `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter` parameter – if it is set to "1" it will cause packets to be dropped. ("2" is okay, if a bit pointless.)

Comment: `sudo ufw status` returns `Status: inactive`, i dont really understand `nft` or `iptables`.
Stopping nginx and running `sudo nc -vvlp 80`, also doesn't get any any connection - but only from the forwarded port. When I connect directly to `serverIP:80` I get everything working correctly. So it seems that it has to do only with forwarding port and only this machine. 
Result of `sudo iptables-save` is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q0CQXswLyNWUdth0Y_h-li0dTREdYW1J/view

(I'm really not experienced enough to read it)
Anything else I can provide?